# How to draw rounded button using canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'd like to draw a rounded button using canvas, what's the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for rectangles. However, you can draw them yourself with [`arcTo`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-arcto), like this ([**demo**](http://phihag.de/2011/so/canvas-roundbuttons.html)):

```
function drawRoundButton(ctx, x, y, width, height, arcsize) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x+arcsize, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x+width-arcsize, y);
    ctx.arcTo(x+width, y, x+width, y+arcsize, arcsize);
    ctx.lineTo(x+width,y+height-arcsize);
    ctx.arcTo(x+width, y+height, x+width-arcsize, y+height, arcsize);
    ctx.lineTo(x+arcsize, y+height);
    ctx.arcTo(x, y+height, x, y-arcsize, arcsize);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y+arcsize);
    ctx.arcTo(x, y, x+arcsize, y, arcsize);
    ctx.lineTo(x+arcsize, y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: @user1020026 Sorry, I don't understand. What exactly is your problem? Can you post a link to what you've got so far?